# NestJS app receives auth CODE from google but not the token. (oauth, passport)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oauth, nestjs

I want to include authentication by Google in my application. I use NestJS on the backend and React on the frontend.
I followed the official documentation and created an endpoint with a guard, using passport.

```
import { AuthService } from '@app/auth/auth.service';
import { Controller, Get, Req, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('api/auth-google')
export class GoogleController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  signinByGoogle(@Req() req) {
    return 'Google signin';
  }

  @Get('callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  signinByGoogleCallback(@Req() req) {
    const googleToken = req.user.accessToken;
    const googleRefeshToken = req.user.refreshToken;

    console.log('tokens', googleToken, googleRefeshToken);

    return this.authService.signinByGoogle(req);
  }
}
```

And here is my strategy:

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

config();

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      clientID: configService.get('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
      clientSecret: configService.get('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth-google/callback',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails } = profile;

    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      firstName: name.givenName,
      lastName: name.familyName,
      accessToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

The problem is, passport strategy expects to receive token after signing in, in the http callback, but there is no token, there is `code` variable, which is not undarstood by the guard and the functionality doesn't wo

Comment: That is a normal part of an OAuth/OIDC flow — you get a `code` from Google that has to be exchanged for a token. That exchange is normally handled by passport. What you usually do is to call passport again from the callback method so it can finish the flow. This should be shown in the passport's documentation.

Comment: It is not shown in the NestJS documentation. To be honest I remember it working 'the old way".

Comment: Maybe the strategy used to implement the implicit flow by default — the one where you get the tokens directly to the browser. This flow, however, should not be used any more and you should use the code flow.